# Serve WordPress from root of site on Bitnami EC2 Ubuntu image

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress

Running Bitnami's Ubuntu Wordpress Image on Amazon EC2.  By default the WordPress install is at /wordpress and there is a static index.html file in the root.   How do I configure Apache and WordPress to serve from the root instead of /wordpress?

I have tried the instructions on this page: http://digitivity.org/10/how-to-serve-your-wordpress-blog-from-the-root-directory-if-its-installed-in-a-subdirectory without success.

I have tried changing the document root to the folder serving the wordpress content, but that just breaks WordPress.

I know I am missing something simple, but not sure what.   Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

1. First of all Log in the wordpress admin panel and change in the “settings” panel the URL.
2. Stop Apache server: sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop apache
3. Edit the following lines in the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf file:

...

DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

...

Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs"

...

# Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/wordpress.conf"

...

4. Start the server: sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start apache

---

if you are having trouble saving your changes due to permission problems, use:

:w !sudo tee %